# How to resend a transaction not recognized by the network?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, pending-transactions

I've sent a simple transaction (no smart contract invocation) while my geth node had no peers attached. It created the transaction fine and returned a transaction identifier.

Even with many nodes connected now, I cannot find this transaction on any block explorer. I presume this means it wasn't broadcasted?

How can I rebroadcast the transaction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `eth.pendingTransactions` to find the transaction you want to resend.

Then

`var tx = eth.pendingTransactions[index]`, replacing index with the index of the transaction you want to resend.

Then

`eth.resend(tx, <optional gas price>, <optional gas limit>)`.

This allows you to change the gas price and gas limit of the resent transaction.

From the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#ethresend).

Comment: Great explanation, but given the number of steps and the fact that code is involved I don't know if you can get away with "just" :)

Comment: Note that pendingTransactions is an array, not a function, so you would retrieve the first pending transaction with `var tx = eth.pendingTransactions[0]`, without parentheses.

Comment: `eth.resend(eth.pendingTransactions[0])
Error: Transaction 0885f7449756ae676259370a7c20dcf1c983f4276b7b333de505460928c1b164 not found`

Answer (score 2):

For what is worth, slightly related.

I've sent a transaction from `MetaMask` with low gas price.

I was searching for a solution to fix it.

Luckily `MetaMask` offers a convenient solution:

[image]

*(great feature, thank you developers)*