# Ethereum tx pending - gas price

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-price, txpool

I made an ethereum tx with 21 gwei gas price. It is now pending since more then one hour. Theoretically when adoption increases and therefore more txs happen and everybody must set enough gas to be included in the Block my tx will never be confirmed due to the blocksize limit.

1. What can I do now to make my tx invalid?
2. Will my tx be removed from all mempools after some time if it gets not confirmed?
3. Before my tx I had 0.4 ETH. After my tx (which is pending now) it shows in MEW 0.1 ETH tough it is pending. Can I just withdraw ally my funds and send the tx again with a higher gas price and therfore make my old tx invalid due to no funds. WOuld MEW allow that?

EDIT: The tx now got confirmed even tough there are 21 pages of tx that payed a higher gas-price in the mempool.

4. Whats the logic behind that?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What can I do now to make my tx invalid?

### Please read [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/31300/9938) because it can help.

> 2) Will my tx be removed from all mempools after some time if it gets
>   not confirmed?

Not sure about this scenario on Ethereum platform, but in Bitcoin some say:

> It should be dropped after 48-72 hours unless someone is
>   rebroadcasting it periodically.

---

> 3) Before my tx I had 0.4 ETH. After my tx (which is pending now) it
>   shows in MEW 0.1 ETH tough it is pending. Can I just withdraw all my
>   funds and send the tx again with a higher gas price and therfore make
>   my old tx invalid due to no funds. WOuld MEW allow that?

Not before you will get refunded.

---

*I don't like making assumptions nor misleading answers, I would love to improve the second item if you have some info to share.*