# How to calculate Estimated Confirmation Duration of a pending transaction?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

How I can calculate Estimated Confirmation Duration

or

Can someone give me a formula to calculate Estimated Confirmation Duration of a pending transaction like etherscan.io do?

[image: image of a pending transaction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no formula.

You are waiting for a miner to pick up your transaction and include it in a block. They are under no obligation to that. They are financially incentivized to do that by the `gasPrice` you *offered* them. If it's taking too long, then offer isn't good enough.

The best you can do is compare to historical norms for similarly-priced transactions. As Nikita pointed out, EthGasStation reports such statistics. It will be a curve, with some completing faster than others.

In a situation like yours with a stalled transaction, you can't be sure it won't mine. You would want to be sure of that before you, say, send it again with a higher gas price.

Have a look over here for a way to get a confirmation that you have cancelled it. [Canceling / overwriting a pending transaction using geth JSON RPC](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9072/canceling-overwriting-a-pending-transaction-using-geth-json-rpc)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

At EthGasStation.info, they have [this](https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php) calculator. On youtube you can find many tutorials how to properly use this tool, although it should be self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks! But I want to calculate Estimated Confirmation Duration in my own block explorer, so I need a math formula.

Comment: So it's a private net ? Then it's easy, it all depends on the amount of miners and transactions. If the block size fits all the transactions, you will hardly ever wait longer than a maximum of two blocks, often times it will only be one.